# Create deployment branch rule with Github REST API

Tags: github-api

I'm using the github rest api to create repo environments:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-an-environment

The api allows us to select `deployment_branch_policy.custom_branch_policies: (boolean)` but I can't find a way of creating a **deployment branch rule** with a custom pattern, like you would do on the UI:

[image]

Is there any way of creating this through the REST api?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do via the [Deployment branch policies API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/branch-policies):

> The Deployment branch policies API allows you to specify custom name patterns that branches must match in order to deploy to an environment. The `deployment_branch_policy.custom_branch_policies` property for the environment must be set to true to use these endpoints. To update the `deployment_branch_policy` for an environment, see "[Create or update an environment](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/environments#create-or-update-an-environment)."
>
> For more information about restricting environment deployments to certain branches, see "[Using environments for deployment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#deployment-branches)."